# aws-sdk-php Multipart file copy from one bucket to another bucket in different regions

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multipart

I am trying to use aws-sdk-php multipart copy to copy from one bucket to another bucket in different regions. It works when on the same regions, but not when in different regions using the below code:

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([     
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',  
    'version' => '2006-03-01', 
    'credentials' => [         
        'key'    => AWS_KEY_ID,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET,
    ]                          
]); 
                           
$copier = new MultipartCopy($s3Client, '/'.$from_bucket_name.'/'.$from_path,        
    [                                                                               
    'bucket' => 'toBucket',                                                                     
    'key' => $upload->client_id . '/videos/' . $upload->file_name, //to path                                                   
    'part_size' => $part_size,                                                                                                          
    'concurrency' => $concurrency                                                   
]);
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, @HonkderHase I did tons of research. I was looking for a way to do programmatically switch regions.

Comment: Afaik you can't just copy data with an API over regions. There are additional costs involved and you need to deal with multiple security accounts. Search for Data Sync in AWS docs